# Extractor not able to maintain mediaplayer states of android

Tags: android, parsing, extractor

I am developing my own extractor like aviextractor for my understanding.

I know the the MediaPlayer calls should be in following order from Application.

```
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource()
mMediaPlayer.prepare()
mMediaPlayer.start()
mMediaPlayer.stop()
```

with my extractor video is playing well( i just want to play video file alone) with above all calls from application.

But when i analysed the logs, my extractor->read()(source->read()) is getting called in the extractor during mMediaPlayer.setDataSource()

Even if i comment mMediaPlayer.prepare() and mMediaPlayer.start() and calling only mMediaPlayer.setDataSource() from Application ,my extractor->read()(source->read()) is getting called in extractor.so i feel my extractor is not mapped properly to the media player states.

can somebody help me to overcome this issue.